# If he... he would have

Tags: past-tense, would, have

Is this sentence correct:

If he returned safely, he would have been hailed as a hero.

Are there any other correct ways of saying this?

Comment: I'd say the past perfect 'had returned' is not replaceable by the past simple in this example.

Answer (score 3):

I would say; Had he returned safely, he would have been hailed as a hero.

Comment: Or, to rephrase the original as little as possible, *if he* ***had*** *returned safely, he would have been hailed as a hero*.